# New levels this week

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Were there any new levels released this Monday, March 10? I haven't had any problems seeing new levels up until now, but I thought new ones were released every Monday, and I didn't have any new ones available (other than the Salvage droid ones which I just can't seem to win). Or, is there something I need to do to unlock them? I have 5 million coins and nothing to spend them on :(

Comment: If you haven't had any problems until now and suddenly there are no levels, then chances are there are simply no levels. Is the pattern of releasing new levels each Monday official or just what you experienced? In the latter case, you can't really expect them to keep going at the same rate and fluctuations are perfectly normal and expected. Also this question is probably off-topic because it's about unreleased content. See the [help section](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for [more info](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: The Feb 28 Apple store update says "New levels now and every Monday!" If there were new levels as promised and I just wasn't seeing the update, I wouldn't call that unreleased content.

Comment: I think releasing new levels every Monday is a lot of work in terms of making new graphics and so on.  Unless they have a bunch of levels stockpiled, their choices are to unlock levels that were only available by special events (Panna City, Imperial Marches, and the new salvage reward ones) or come up with new art and design each week.  The first would probably irritate players who spent a lot of time/bux to get the  new levels, and the second requires work on their part.  My guess is that they regret suggesting that they would release levels every Monday.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they just were released. looks like 36 floors in all.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. No answers (that I can see) on their Facebook page, either. Last week Disney Interactive announced major layoffs, so there may be some sort of restructuring going on that's distracting them, but that's only speculation. I don't know if the layoffs affect the TDS team at all.

Comment: I hope not, the android version is buggy as hell. Last thing it needs is less people working on it.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently sitting with 99 levels and waiting for new levels.

I think they have an issue as with each level you have it gives you 1% off the level price. There are several levels I can see but just cannot purchase. Whether they are waiting till the end of the latest event to release the new ones we will see.

Comment: I don't think it's the difference between 99 and 100 levels that is preventing additional levels, though I was wondering how that discount would be applied.  There are many players already with 100 levels or more and I haven't heard about any problems with the discount from that.

Answer (score 0):

I have build 100 level and wait for new ones to come. But today my level counter says i have 118. my wish came tru? No i counted them all and there are only 100. :(
And still no new ones in sight. [image]

Comment: The level counter often gets temporarily increased when using a "Level Mover" VIP on the Imperial levels, in my experience.  You can actually see the number of levels indicator in the upper right fluctuate as you move an Imperial level around. The temporary inaccurate increase usually goes away after a few openings and closings for me.  This is on iOS.

Comment: Same on android

Answer (score 0):

See it for your self. It seems as if someone at disney interactive has published everything planned for The next month in One day. Maybe it was The Last act before The layoff. This time it was Not The emeror but disney himself.

[image]